# can't terminate process using WMI but taskkill works

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, wmi

My user is in the Administrators group.  I am using the .NET WMI API (System.Management) to kill a process using this code:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope("\root\cimv2");
scope.Connect();
var query = new ObjectQuery(
    string.Format("Select * from Win32_Process Where ProcessID = {0}",
        processId));
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
var coll = searcher.Get().GetEnumerator();
coll.MoveNext();
var mgmtObj = (ManagementObject)coll.Current;
var ret = (uint) mgmtObj.InvokeMethod("Terminate");
// ret == 2 here, meaning "Access Denied"
```

It's failing to kill the process and returning a `2` (`Access Denied`).  However if I use:

```
Process.Start("cmd", string.Format("/c \"taskkill /f /pid {0}\"", processId));
```

the process gets killed.  (but if I leave out `/f` it fails).

Is there any way to terminate the process using WMI?

**EDIT:** I found the following on
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393907(v=vs.85).aspx:

> To terminate a process that you do not own, enable the
>   SeDebugPrivilege privilege.

The page provides VBScript code but how would I do this in C#?

Answer (score 3):

That is only possible with some API calls which are only available via pinvoke - for complete C# source code see [here](http://hintdesk.com/c-how-to-enable-sedebugprivilege/).