# How to kill process on remote computer with wmi

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm trying to kill a process on a remote computer, but it's not working, and i'm not getting any errors.
I'm using this code:

```
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + txtMaquina.Text + "\\root\\cimv2");
            scope.Connect();
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_process where name = '" + lstProcessos.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in objectCollection)
                managementObject.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
```

The computer name is `txtMaquina.Text` and the process name i'm getting from a selected item on a `ListView`

Someone have any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to remotely terminate a process using WMI and C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993363/unable-to-remotely-terminate-a-process-using-wmi-and-c-sharp)

Comment: `lstProcessos.SelectedItem.ToString()` is probably incorrect.. it's probably returning the Type name..  (aka `ListViewItem`).. clearly that is not what you want.. ListViews can be fairly complex controls (that is,  If this were a listbox control, the selectedItem would probably have a `Text` property on it.. )

Comment: if you're binding the control, the value is generally in the dataItem property; which you'll explicitly cast from object to string..... just put a debug point down and look into the `lstProcessos.SelectedItem` instance (using Local / Watch windows.. or hovering over the code snippet itself.. or using the immeidate console..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem using this solution on Code Project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18146/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-Proce

Comment: Hi, why not explain better which was your specific problem and how you could resolve it?.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Because it's a too long solution. Couldn't explain better here.

Answer (score 3):

> and i'm not having any error

That's because you don't actually check for an error.  You are probably hoping for an exception but that's not what the Terminate method does.  It returns an error code.  You cannot ignore the return value of ManagementObject.InvokeMethod().

So start solving the problem by getting that exception you don't have right now:

```
foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in objectCollection) {
    int reason = (int)managementObject.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
    switch (reason) {
        case 0: break;
        case 2: throw new Exception("Access denied"); break;
        case 3: throw new Exception("Insufficient privilege"); break;
        case 8: throw new Exception("Unknown failure"); break;
        case 9: throw new Exception("Path not found"); break;
        case 21: throw new Exception("Invalid parameter"); break;
        default: throw new Exception("Terminate failed with error code " + reason.ToString()); break;
    }
}
```

Now you know where to start looking.

Comment: it`s not even entering the foreach.

Comment: Ah, yes, very helpful of you to post that into a comment instead of your question.  Bit of a toss-up between having to fix your ListView or fixing your event handler or using MessageBox.Show("Process no longer running").

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from the parameters :

- **txtMaquina.Text:** must be the machine name.
- **lstProcessos.SelectedItem.ToString():** must be the exe name like *Taskmgr.exe*

I've run your code on my computer and I works fine with the right values in the input parameters.
As  Brett said, you could debug it, use immediate windows or run the code snippet in an unit test fixture.